# How does state transition matrix indicate time-varying system, but $A$ matrix is constant?

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, transition-matrix, steady-state

When I determine whether a linear dynamical system is time-varying or not by looking at the state transition matrix, I get confused by the following:

Normally, I look at the $A$ matrix to determine whether a system is time-varying.  Obviously, if $A$ is a function of time $A(t)$, then it is time-varying, and if not, then it is not a time-varying system.

But, the state transition matrix looks like $\phi(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}[(sI-A)^-1]$.  And then $\phi(t)$ turns out to be a function of time.

What I'm trying to understand is how the state transition matrix is a function of time, but the $A$ matrix is not?  I am intuitively trying to rationalize this.

The state transition matrix indicates time-varying system, but $A$ matrix is constant?  So is the system $\dot x(t)=\phi(t)x(t)$ time-varying or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a simple system $\dot{x} = x$, then $A=1$ and $\phi(t,t_0) = e^{t-t_0}$.
That is $A$ is constant, but the system response is time varying. In general this
will be the case unless $A=0$.

If you have $\phi(t,t_0)$ in general you have $\dot{\phi}(t,t_0) = A(t) \phi(t,t_0)$, or $A(t) = \phi(t,t_0)^{-1} \dot{\phi}(t,t_0) = \phi(t_0,t) \dot{\phi}(t,t_0)$, so you can determine if $A$ is time varying or not.

**Addendum**: It is not too hard to show that the system is time invariant **iff**
$\phi(t,t_0) = \phi(t-t_0,0)$ for all $t,t_0$. A little more work shows that in this case $A$ is essentially constant.

Comment: So basically you are saying that $A$ being a function of time, is a sufficient but not necessary condition for a system to be time-varying, right?  If that's true, then I'm still wondering how to get some general guidelines of determining if system is time-varying, or LTI or neither.

Comment: Not really. I am saying that even for a constant $A$ the system response will typically be time varying. I am just showing that for a simple time invariant system that the system response is time varying. If $A$ is constant, then the system will be time invariant, but the state response will (usually) be time varying.

Comment: oh, i see.  This is an important distinction then:  the "System" being time-varying versus the state response being "time-varying".  Those are different things, you seem to be implying.

Comment: Well, yes, the dynamics are completely described by $A$ (which may be constant), but in general the responses will be time varying. Think of $A$ as the 'law describing motion'. The laws may be fixed but the motion need not be.

Comment: I added a little more info.

Comment: Okay, still confused.  Are any of the following *3* statements true? 1) $A$ describes the “system”. 2) $\phi(t)$ describes the “system response” (I’ve often heard it called the “state transition matrix”). 3) the word “state response”, is the same as “system response”.  If those three  statements are true, then I suppose I still don’t know why this is not also true: if $A$ is time-varying, then $\phi(t)$ is time-varying.  And hence, as I said before $A$ being a function of time is sufficient but not necessary for the system response ($\phi(t)$) to be time-varying.

Comment: The dynamical system is $\dot{x}=A(t) x$. System response is a general term used to describe the behavior of the system. The state transition matrix is a function of two parameters, and gives the solution at time $t$ to an initial condition $x_0$ at time $t_0$, that is, $x(t) = \phi(t,t_0) x_0$. In general, $\phi(t,t_0)$ is not a constant, regardless of $A$. My answer gives an example of a system with a constant $A=1$, but the response is definitely not constant.

Comment: Note that $A(t)$ is essentially constant **iff** the system is time invariant. The state transition matrix is never constant (except when $A=0$).

Comment: I mostly understand what you're saying.  But why the qualifier "essentially" is necessary?

Comment: You can redefine $A$ on a set of measure zero without changing the solution. That is where the 'essential' comes from.